# How to convert an iterator-like that has a `next()` methode to a regular `begin`/`end` iterator pair?

Tags: c++, iterator

In the codebase I inherited, there is a class that look like an iterator (this isn’t the exact code, but the logic is similar).

```cpp
template <class T>
struct IteratorLike {
    T* next() &; // either return a pointer to a valid value or nullptr
};
```

The way you use it is very similar to the way you use Rust iterators:

```cpp
IteratorLike<...> it = ...;
while(auto* item = it.next()) {
    do_something(*item);
}
```

How do I convert it to make it compatible with C++ range-based for loop, algorithms, or range-v3? I’m using C++14 (gcc5.5 to be more precise), so I can’t have a sentinel type that is different from the type of the iterator itself.

---

So far it seems that the easiest way is to store both the iterator and the next value in my wrapper:

```cpp
template <class T>
class MyIterator {
private:
    IteratorLike<T> m_iter;
    T* m_value;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&; 
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    reference operator*() const {
        assert(m_value && "trying to read past the end of the iterator");
        return *m_value;
    }   
    pointer operator->() {
        // I’m not sure the assert is needed here
        assert(m_value && "trying to read past the end of the iterator");
        return m_value;
    }   

    // Prefix increment
    MyIterator& operator++() {
        m_value = m_iter.next();
        return *this;
    }   

    // Postfix increment
    MyIterator operator++(int) {
        MyIterator tmp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }
    
    // used by `my_collection.begin()`
    explicit MyIterator(IteratorLike<T> iter)
        : m_iter{m_iter}
        , m_value{this->self.next()}
    {}  
    // missing operator == and operator != as well as the constructor
    // used `my_collection.end()
};
```

However, I fail to understand what `my_collection.end()` should return (EDIT: I just check, I can’t default-initialize `m_iter`), nor how to have meaningful comparison operators.

Note: I’m basically trying to do the exact reverse of [this](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/04/16/an-alternative-design-to-iterators-and-ranges-using-stdoptional/).

Comment: Sounds like in this case an `end` iterator is an iterator with a `nullptr` internal pointer value.

Comment: I worked with such codebase in the past, and it is a the pain in the neck. You would not use `my_collection.end()` to get the end of the sequence. Instead, you will use empty-constructed iterator (in the mold of stream iterators), and in your `!=` operator you'd consider two iterators equal if one is default-constructed, and second has nullptr returned by internal iterator-like.

Comment: > "Sounds like in this case an end iterator is an iterator with a nullptr internal pointer value."

Yes, but what value should I use for `m_iter`?  EDIT: I just double checked, `IteratorLike` isn’t default-constructible.

Comment: use a `std::optional<IteratorLike<T>>` (or `boost::optional`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IteratorLike` isn't `default` constructible, but is obviously *copy* constructible, you could use the instance you have to construct your `end()` iterator too. Example:

```
// used by `my_collection.begin()`
explicit MyIterator(const IteratorLike<T>& iter) :
    m_iter{iter},
    m_value{m_iter.next()}
{}

// used by `my_collection.end()`
MyIterator(const IteratorLike<T>& iter, std::nullptr_t) :
    m_iter{iter},
    m_value{nullptr}
{}

bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) const {
    return m_value != rhs.m_value;
}
```

Then in `my_collection`:

```
template<typename T>
class my_collection {
public:
    MyIterator<T> begin() { return MyIterator<T>{itlike}; }
    MyIterator<T> end() { return {itlike, nullptr}; }

private:    
    IteratorLike<T> itlike;
};
```